# Change Activiti Diagram

Tags: process, diagram, activiti

I created a simple model and I started many processes, they are waiting the approval. While they are waiting if I update my diagram, what happens to these processes? And how can I update the diagram? I tried edit model and saved, but it didn't change.

Answer (score 2):

Every definition has version. All process instances running based on definition with old version. You can migrate all runnig instances to new version of definition by `org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.SetProcessDefinitionVersionCmd`.
http://forums.activiti.org/content/migrating-process-instances-newer-versions

But be careful
This command will NOT perform any migration magic and simply set the process definition version in the database, assuming that the user knows, what he or she is doing.

Comment: I just want to add my 2 cents to the cautionary note above. While you CAN migrate running instances to a different process version, extreme care should be taken if doing so. A simply change to a process variable or service class could easily crash your instance, putting you in a very bad place.